# Should people voting to close explain why they're voting to close unless it's obvious?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it acceptable to vote to close a question without leaving a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39057/is-it-acceptable-to-vote-to-close-a-question-without-leaving-a-comment)

Should people voting to close for non-blatant cases be encouraged to explain in comments (ie not just a multiple-choice radio button) why they're voting to close it? Moderators aren't at much risk of having reputation harmed by serial downvoting, are they?

**Background**: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734157/reproducibility-in-scientific-programming) has a vote to close, and I'm wondering if it's because that person doesn't like "best practices" questions.

Comment: they probably should, yeah, but that doesn't mean there should be a UI mechanism to force the issue.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks for that link (you're trying to close me, aren't you!?!), but that's talking about a blatant case.

Comment: Yes, I voted to close. And yes, that question references a specific case, but the answers and comments there cover the same ground as what you're asking here.