# Have some users gotten too pedantic with closing and voting down answers?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions, down-votes, badge-request

Quite frequently as a user, I see posts like this:

> On Linux systems (either 32- or 64-bit), what is the size of pid_t,
>   uid_t, and gid_t?

Source: [Size of pid_t, uid_t, gid_t on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922761/size-of-pid-t-uid-t-gid-t-on-linux)

It could probably be argued that this post does not meet the guidelines; for example, it shows no evidence of research.  Yet this question was useful to me and a number of other people.

I've posted questions like this in the past - some of the questions are well received, some are voted down or flagged for closing.

It seems that some people are too ready to vote down or close a question without really reading the question and trying to understand whether the question may be useful to other people.

It seems that some users have gotten too pedantic with closing and voting down answers?

Maybe a badge is needed for people who try to offer "helpful" comments when they close or vote down a question?

Comment: You gave an example of a question that *wasn't* closed or downvoted, and you use it to argue that too many questions are closed too quickly. Do you have an example of a question that *was* closed that shouldn't have been?

Comment: Your example was also from 2009. Do you have a more recent example?

Comment: @David - here is a similar question that I posted that had two close votes within seconds of posting: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969582/how-do-i-iterate-through-all-the-entries-in-etc-passwd-using-c).  My 'bad' question seems very similar in style and format to the example.

Comment: @Bill - has the criteria changed between 2009 and now?  Maybe I've been influenced by older posts?

Comment: Yes, the criteria has changed a lot since 2009.  I don't think that question would be accepted now.

Comment: Ah, that's the source of my misunderstanding then!

Comment: One thing that you need to keep in mind is that when self-answering a question the question will be held to exactly the same standards as any other question you didn't self-answer.  It needs to include just as much information and be answerable by anyone else, and it will be judged entirely independently of any answers you may give, just as the answers should be judged independently of the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) and of [Is it acceptable to vote to close a question without leaving a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39057/is-it-acceptable-to-vote-to-close-a-question-without-leaving-a-comment)

Comment: 2009 ... 2013 ... it shouldn't matter?  I've been told in other circumstances that the age of the question/answer doesn't give a free pass if it doesn't meet *today's* quality standards.

Comment: @John I don't quite understand your reasoning. The votes were cast in 2009, using different criteria. Should we downvote it now just because it doesn't conform to today's standards? If so, I feel sorry for all those users that asked perfectly acceptable questions back in 2009. We just tend to leave old questions be - some of them may be very good references. That said, quite a few old, good questions has been closed (closing doesn't mean deleting).

Comment: @Dukeling: The problem with older questions that no longer meet the current criteria is they are used as evidence that similar questions can be asked today.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know, but that's no reason to downvote them, though maybe something needs to be done. I don't think closing (all of) them is a good idea either, as it might be good to have them accrue answers. And usually (but not always) people who ask bad questions don't justify their question with a reference to another question.